# CST/CDT date to MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm in oracle

Tags: oracle, csv, date, datetime, timezone

I have a csv file with data in timezones including CST and CDT.

For eg:
        07-Mar-2017 11:00:00 PM CST
        03-Oct-2017 11:00:00 PM CDT

The date field in the csv is being stored as a varchar2(30).

The target date field needs to be converted to the format shown below:

```
     MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm
```

How can we go about doing this conversion in oracle considering we have two timezines in the source file?

Please help.

Thanks Much
Tina

Comment: Convert both of them to cst or cdt. And store it. While displaying again convert back... Or you can store them in same time zone. It all depends on your requirements and what you want to do with that data

Comment: MT0 already showed you how to do the right thing. Just to make sure you are not missing the main point though: You said "The target date field needs to be converted to the format...." which is wrong already. The target field should be data type `timestamp with time zone` - NOT A STRING. Timestamps do not have "a format" - you choose that format only when you DISPLAY the stored data, but the stored data itself does not have a format.

Comment: Assuming by CST and CDT, you mean US Central Standard Time and US Central Daylight Time (and not Cuba Standard/Daylight Time, or China Standard Time (which has no daylight time)) then you do not have two separate time zones.  You have one time zone, whose time zone ID is `America/Chicago`

Comment: @Matt Johnson .The timezone is US Central Standard Time and US Central Daylight Time.

Comment: @mathguy, the target timezone would be CST

Comment: You seemed to be confusing two different issues.  You have local time values which correctly switch between CST and CDT.  This is normal. 
 Then you say you want to convert it to a different format.  That is an entirely separate issue, and as others have said - you don't want to actually store it in the database as a varchar.  So at the end of the day, there is no time zone conversion necessary - just import the data with respect to US Central time.

Comment: Assuming the date-time values are as you show them, and assuming they are stored in the proper data type (`date` or `timestamp` of some sort), and you are asking about DISPLAYING the stored values (for reading by humans), and you want the displayed value to be in the format you have in your post: It seems reasonable that both dates would have the time-of-day of 23:00 (according to either CST or CDT, whichever was in force on the corresponding date). Are you asking HOW to get that displayed value, as a string?

Comment: However, you are saying that the values are STORED as `VARCHAR2(30)`, which is already a bad thing. Why are they stored that way? Can that be fixed?

Comment: @mathguy Yes, it can be fixed. We can alter the source table to store it as timestamp. My question is - do I need to convert CDT values to CST before moving them to my target table.

Comment: @Tina - if you store as `timestamp with time zone` then you need no conversion. However, if you must convert to `timestamp` and have no time zone marker, then it is a question to the **business users**. In most cases they will not want a conversion (if they understand the question, which most won't). If an event occurred at 11 PM CDT in the summer, and another event occurred at 11 PM CST in winter, they (the business users) will want to show 11 PM for both timestamps. Whatever the "current" time zone, either CST or CDT, was in force **on that date**.

Comment: I spoke to my business users and it seems they do not want a conversion around it. But they can change their mind anytime, So lets see :) Thanks so much for your inputs @mathguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` to read it as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type. If you want to convert it to a common time zone then use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to convert it to the UTC time zone (as an example).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ac5/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
SELECT '07-Mar-2017 11:00:00 PM CST' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03-Oct-2017 11:00:00 PM CDT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03-Oct-2017 11:00:00 PM CST' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           value,
           'DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZD',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
         'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI'
       ) AS utc_time
FROM   your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ac5/4/0)**:

```
|         UTC_TIME |
|------------------|
| 03-07-2017 23:00 |
| 10-03-2017 23:00 |
| 10-03-2017 23:00 |
```

Comment: Thanks Much@MT0. It seems the target is going to be in CST. I got the following dates by pointing the query you showed above to 'CST'                                                                                                                                                                                                            07-Mar-2017 11:00:00 PM CST 03-07-2017 23:00
03-Oct-2017 11:00:00 PM CDT 10-04-2017 00:00

Comment: So 3rd Oct 11 PM CDT  changes to 4th Oct 00:00 CST